# Get value from dictionary in nested list without key

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting back the following from an API `requests.get` call using requests:

```
[[{'DOI': '10.1021/nn1025675'}], [{'DOI': '10.1128/mcb.00032-10'}]]
```

I need to get the values (eg `'10.1021/nn1025675'`) from this and pass it to another `get` call. I can’t seem to get the value without the key, though because it is nested in a list.

How can I get the value out and into my parameters without the key`‘DOI’`?

Comment: You will have to use multiple for loops or you will have to use list comprehension to get all the nested values.

Comment: The api is in this form ````https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/10.1002/adfm.201505328```` and doesn’t take a key. And for requests.get you can only pass key: value pairs, so I need to add the value as using ````f”https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/{doi}”````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = [[{'DOI': '10.1021/nn1025675'}], [{'DOI': '10.1128/mcb.00032-10'}]]
```

Making the `dict.values` a `list`

```
>>> res = []

>>> for arr in data:
...     res.append(list(arr[0].values())[0])
...
>>> print(res)
['10.1021/nn1025675', '10.1128/mcb.00032-10']
```

And if you don't mind destroying the dict, it's much easier:

```
>>> res = []

>>> for arr in data:
...     res.append(arr[0].popitem()[1])
...
>>> print(res)
['10.1021/nn1025675', '10.1128/mcb.00032-10']
```